# Find value in String and delete it an everything else after it

Tags: javascript

If I have a string which could be either

```
index.php?value1=123&value2=xyz
```

or

```
index.php?value2=xyz
```

how would I remove `&value2=xyz` or `?value2=xyz` if `value2` exists in the string?

xyz will be random each time whereas the name value2 will rename constant but the length of xyz will always be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest approach is:

```
var valueToKeep = value.split(/[&?]value2/)[0];
```

Note that this will remove everything after the `&value2` or `?value2` part. As an alternative, I would propose the following, which will remove the `value2=...` part, even if it occurs mid-url:

```
var valueToKeep = value.replace(/value2[^&]*&?/, "");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LTH7j/1/

Comment: When the user logs out of the site the last page they looked at is stored in the db along with the parameters needed for that page.  When they log back in they are redirected to the last page they looked at.  Also, when they log in a new session token is created and stored in the db and added to the href.location of the log on script so it can be stored in a session.  If they log in and don't move to another page and log out again the token will be saved in the db as a param of the last page so I want to remove it if it is there before the last page is saved to the db.  Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, it kinda makes sense. Updated my answer.